# PHP var 1 and 2 equal when total differend

Tags: php

```
$typeNow = 0;
while(...) {
if($typeNow == $menu["type"]) { echo '<p>'.$typeNow .' '.$menu["type"].'<i>Of</i></p>'; } else {  if(strlen($typeNow) > 1) { echo '<p><i>'.$tussenstuk.'</i></p>'; } }
                    $typeNow = $menu["type"];
                    echo '<p>'.$menu["val1"].'</p>';
```

Output:

```
0 appertiefOf Love bubbels
*** Gerookte zalmrolletjes van kruidenkaas en compotte van granny smith
*** Zuppa aroma di Amore
*** Love fish meets passion
*** Filet van pure liefde met roquefortsaus
*** framboise forever
```

output2 (other page):

```
0 voorgerechtOf
Noordzee vissoep
voorgerecht voorgerechtOf
Duo van meloen met zwarte woudham
***
Kalfswangetjes met porto en warme groentjes
hoofdgerecht hoofdgerechtOf
Schartongrolletjes met gerookte zalm & spinazie
***
Café glacé
```

the odd thing is **$typeNow == $menu["type"])** where the first is 0 and the second is appertief and still see this as equal

Comment: This is not strange. You are comparing a string to a number. Expect weirdness. On a serious note, converting `"abc"` to a number gives `0` because there are no numeric characters at the start of that string.

Comment: Oyeah not realized :( thank you sir

Comment: Use `===` instead of `==`. PHP thinks `"string" == 0` should be `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't compare a number (especially zero) to a string.
Look at this:

```
var_dump( 0 == "php" );
```

It gives `true`

Here you are, the types comparison table: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

You may need to change the `$typeNow` to string and compare by `===`

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to *never* use `==` if you can help it. It can end up executing code if you compare an object with a `__toString()` method.